# How can I add multiple variables to 'Blobs in a Jar' animation?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the classic "Blobs in a Jar" code to include more than one character variable. I want several different "blobs" to appear at the same time; currently the standard version has only the one "blob". But, every time I try to add more than one variable, only the first or last one will be read, and the rest will be ignored.

[Here is the entire original code for reference.](http://www.mf2fm.com/rv/dhtmlblobs-in-a-jar.php) The line that I am referencing is at the start of the code, `var charc=String.fromCharCode(9679); // a blob - can be changed to charc='hello' or charc='*' for a different effect`

I have tried the following lists:

`var charc='hello', 'hi', 'bonjour', 'hola', 'aloha';`

I have also tried removing the commas, which stopped any variables from being read.

```
var charc='hello'
    charc=,'hi'
    charc=,'bonjour'
    charc=,'hola'
    charc=,'aloha';
```

This has also been tried with repeating lines of 'var charc' individually, instead of them being nested like this.

As far as I understand, this single line should be the only part of the code I need to edit, but I am afraid there's something else I'm missing here. Do I need to have additional instructions for multiple variables to be read at once? My very very very last resort will be using the entire script for every instance of blob that I want to have and hoping that's acceptable web-coding practice. 
EDIT: I did try doing this, with some interesting results. The last instance is read and duplicated for every other instance, but the others are frozen in their first frame of animation while the last instance moves. Pretty cool, but it would be way cooler if I could get the other words to show up as well.

I've looked through as many Javascript help articles as I can stand, but they only go so far when I have no previous experience with Javascript. Sorry if the answer is kinda obvious ^^"

Answer (score 0):

Defining more variables with the same name won't do anything, as only the most recently defined one will be accessible.

The code on the page doesn't support multiple words, and such a feature would need to be implemented.